# how to change css img element with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html, setattribute

I would like to change the CSS using javascript so that I can dynamically adjust the height of a single image on my web page. This is being done so that the image will fit nicely in the viewable screen no matter what the screen size.

My CSS

```
.wrapper img {
height: 630px;
}
```

My Div

```
<div class="wrapper" id="imageDiv"></div>
```

What javascript code should I use to change the CSS height to say 200px.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set the height in percentage if the goal is to autoadjust based on viewport height etc:

```
.wrapper img {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Anyway:

```
document.getElementById('imageDiv').style.height = '200px';
```

Comment: I tried using viewport, but it didn't resize the images like a normal html img src. I using javascript to cycle through a series of images. Here's a the javascript code I'm using: images[current] = document.createElement("img");

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
document.getElementById("imageDiv").style.height="200px";
```

(this would only change it for that one element.)

Comment: I'm sorry to have bothered you on this. It turns out that I was creating the image element using javascript in an array. I've got it sorted. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery, you could just put inside the method that you want:

```
$('img.wrapper').css('height','200px');
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I found the problem, see above comments I made.